# Swapping class when drop box option is selected

Tags: jquery, css, class, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down box that has the options "vertical" and "horizontal" in it.

```
<select class="nav-select">
    <option id="one" value="1">Vertical</option>
    <option id="two" value="2">Horizontal</option>
</select>
```

When an option is picked from the drop-down box I want it to change the class "body-wrap horizontal-nav" to "body-wrap vertical-nav".

```
<div class="body-wrap vertical-nav">
```

So far I have written some jQuery but cannot seem to get it working. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("two")) {
        $("body div").addClass('body-wrap horizontal-nav');       
    } 
    else if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("one") {
        $("body div").addClass('body-wrap vertical-nav');
    }

});
```

Comment: you forgot to close `ElseIf` closing braces :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `hasID()` is a real jQuery function.

Anyway even if it was, that's the wrong approach: you're only checking once, on `$(document).ready()`. You should check every time the select changes, possibly something like this:

```
$('.nav-select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('div.body-wrap').removeClass('horizontal-nav').addClass('vertical-nav');
  } else {
    $('div.body-wrap').removeClass('vertical-nav').addClass('horizontal-nav');
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am watching it in firebug and nothing changes in the div. Here is a pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gtDGp @drquicksilver

Comment: You hadn't wrapped it in doc.ready and also you didn't have a working jQuery include (in the pen, at least). Here is a working pen with the same basic code as yours: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HCEap

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove one of the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("two")) {
        $("body div").removeClass('vertical-nav').addClass('horizontal-nav');       
    } 
    else if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("one") {
        $("body div").removeClass('horizontal-nav').addClass('vertical-nav');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Remove Old class add New class**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("two")) {
        $("body div").removeClass('vertical-nav').addClass('horizontal-nav');       
    } 
    else if ($('.nav-select option').hasId("one") {
        $("body div").removeClass('horizontal-nav').addClass('vertical-nav');
    }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am watching it in firebug and nothing changes in the div. Here is a pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gtDGp @Nikhil